# Making container in table-cell fill the whole height of its parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align content without using flexbox because there were some problems with our use case, so I am trying to do it with table which works fine as vertically aligning goes but the problem is that the content inside doesn't fill the remaining height, is there possible to do that through CSS somehow ?

https://jsfiddle.net/s38haqm5/25/

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="container">
          Hello world
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cella">
        Cell2
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>


.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%; 
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: auto;
  max-height: none;
}

.cella {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  max-height: none;
}

.row {
  display: table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define parent height. Now your `.cell` does not have any hight set, so `.container` doesnt have any value to calculate the 100% from.
Simply add some height to `.cell`, for example `.cell {height: 30px;}` (just like you have on `.cella`.)

Since `.cella` and `.cell` are same, Im assuming you might need this bit of an advice.
If you want your cells to be the same with the fact that one of them needs to be styled differently, add the same class on all of them, and then add id to the one that needs to be different and then style the id as you want. Keep in mind that the cell with class and id will have css values combined from both class and id

Comment: I think this wouldnt work since because we don't know what the height of the cell will be, it will be based on the tallest element in a row. Its a dataGrid from material UI, so the rows/cells are generated based on the content.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me just fine. Give it a try and tell me if it fulfills your wishes.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell" id="cell1">
        <div class="container">
          Hello world
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell" id="cell2">
        Cell2
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<style>
.container {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0; /*shorthand for top:0, left:0, bottom:0, right:0*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  /* for centering content within container
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
 */
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: min-content;
  width: 100px;
}

.row {
  display: table
}
</style>
```

What I have done is that I have set your `.container` to position absolute and parent `.cell` to relative, so it becomes a containing block of the `.container`, `inset:0` makes the absolute `.container` strech over the whole relative `.cell.` parent. Hope this does the job!